# perl, BerkeleyDB and CDS mode

Tags: database, perl, berkeley-db

Is there an example of using CDS mode for BerkeleyDB with perl on a Debian system?  I am initializing with:

```
$db_env = new BerkeleyDB::Env
-Home => "/tmp",
-Flags => DB_CREATE | DB_INIT_CDB | DB_INIT_MPOOL
or die "cannot open environment $BerkeleyDB::Error";
```

And I am getting an "invalid argument" error for DB_INIT_MPOOL. If I omit it, I get complaints about "environment did not include a memory pool" (for either Hash or Btree databases).

Comment: Works fine for me, perhaps [upgrade libdb](http://sleepycat.com/) plus headers to 4.8 or 5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> And I am getting an "invalid argument"
>   error for DB_INIT_MPOOL. If I omit it,
>   I get complaints about "environment
>   did not include a memory pool" (for
>   either Hash or Btree databases).

You're typically getting this first kind of error ("Invalid argument") if you try to create an environment where an environment with a *different configuration* (different flags) already exists.

As for the second error (missing memory pool), it's because you're instructing BDB to do `DB_INIT_CDB` without `DB_INIT_MPOOL` - that's not possible, CDB *has to go* with a memory pool.

Take a look at [this other BDB/CDB question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5752815/269126), I've left some pointers to documentation there that might prove interesting to you.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer to this is to remove the files __db.XXX, where XXX is three numbers. For example in my environment I had three files, __db.001, __db.002 and __db.003.

I know this is an old post and the previous answer essentially is the same thing but the example would have helped me when I stumbled over this post while googling yesterday.